# Cast to Timestamp in Java

Tags: java, spring, wordpress, pojo

i need a support,

i want to create product importer to woocommerce in Java.

One of column in "wp_posts" table is Timestamp type. But unfortunatelly if in wordpress i won't publicate a post/product, value of this field is "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

When my code try to cast the post to POJO Object, i have error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Value '......' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp.
```

How should i cast "0000-00-00 00:00:00" to Timestamp in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is caused by JDBC, add zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull at the end of the jdbc connection string will fix.
like this

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Refer: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/2326

Answer (score 0):

Many DB Implemetations don't supported null in Timestamp column. So if you have 'null' in DB it may be represented as something like "0000-00-00 00:00:00". You can better use nullable Date column.